# Error on publishing .net core 2.0 angular spa web app on azure

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

Since this morning, I'm trying to publish from visual studio code with the **azure app service** extension my Angular Spa application but when I try to navigate to the url, I get this page :

[image]

I publish my file into my pc using this CLI command :

```
dotnet build -c Release && dotnet publish -c Release --output "./release"
```

My csproj look like this :

```csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <UserSecretsId>b7354f74-12e8-4958-a0d5-4fdc25e86285</UserSecretsId>

    <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
    <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Gardendynamics.Commons" Version="1.0.0-ci-76" />
    <PackageReference Include="Gardendynamics.Tiers" Version="1.0.0-ci-50" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PicaplantBack.Database\PicaplantBack.Database.csproj" IncludeAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

    <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:preprod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and i was able to solve it by following the details,

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10666

The problem i had was i had to edit my package.json file and remove the --extractCss parameter from the start and build property. from:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
```

to:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
```